# Indexing a page in which the content is discovered in a map

Tags: seo, javascript, sitemap, web-crawlers

We want to improve our site's SEO. The page is a GWT (javascript based) web page and its content is discovered through a map or a GPS.

Now we have just a normal landing html page, and the map and the detail pages referenced in a sitemap.xml.

I want to achieve better results by:

- Leaving the html landing page as it is right now, but pointing to the map page (now it does it through JavaScript).
- In the map (JavaScript page) use the  trick and change the body in the servelet with H1, H2, H3... but... do we put a list of links to the details simulating the map of the whole world? Or is better to leave this to the sitemap.xml? With the first way we keep the hierarchy (landing-->map-->details).
- In the details page use the  trick and write html info.

So the question is is it better to have a sitemap.xml or to change the page content to point to the details (they can be thousands)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about a Javascript-based web app, you might want to take a look at [Google's recommendation for making AJAX pages crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

If your app observes the [URL mapping and HTML snapshot scheme](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification), [it's already visible to crawlers.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot)

Comment: Yes, I have already seen that. But what I want to know is if it is better to use sitemaps or a lot of links in the "map for crawling page"

Comment: @PabloCastilla Both as long as you're not link spamming and as long as it doesn't impede the usability of the site. Links only visible to bots are bad. Helpful links for users are good (in context even better).